# Scripting the initialization of a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to script the creation of a machine image that includes MySQL with some seed data.

I'm looking for a way to start the MySQL database engine, run a `.sql` script to create the data, and then shutdown the engine.  Is there a best way to do this?

It looks like I could use the `--init-file` argument of `mysqld` to launch `mysql` and run the script, but how would I cause the database engine to shutdown after the script completes?

I'm on Ubuntu if it matters.

Comment: What if you issue `mysqld shutdown` immediately after?

Answer (score 1):

Just do these three commands in one script:

```
service mysql start
mysql -umyuser -pmypass < /path/to/your/startup.sql
service mysql stop
```

You may consider using `skip-networking` in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file so that the database is not accidentally accessed by anyone else for the short perios when it's up and running. In which case add the `--socket` argument to your `mysql` client command.